# How to create a launch image or how to get an empty status bar

Tags: iphone, image, ios-simulator, statusbar, launch

I want to create a launch image for my app. The [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) states:

> For iPhone and iPod touch create launch images that include the status bar region in the following sizes:
>
> - 320 x 480 pixels
> - 640 x 960 pixels (high resolution)

I've tried to [screenshot my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173682/how-to-create-high-resolution-iphone-launch-image) within the iPhone Simulator. But here the status bar is on the screen including signal strength, carrier, time and battery life. So there are two possibilities:

- include status bar with wrong information
- clean status bar for myself (use Photoshop or something like this and then I have to be aware of the gradients ...)
- leave out status bar, but then violating the HIG (because images are of size 320x460 and 640x920)

Is there a way to hide the informations in the status bar in iPhone Simulator? Should I leave out the status bar as talked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803500/iphone-app-submission-status-bar-and-screenshots)?

**Solution:**

It seems that all three answers are right. Here are the solutions:

1. Supply images of size 320x480 / 640x960 with or without cleared status bar
2. Crop images (without status bar). Images have the size 320x460 and 640x920 then.

To be conform to the HIG I'll choose option no. 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it without doing anything? I think the correct toolbar will be overlaid on top of the image, from the looks of things.

Comment: No I haven't tried. Now I tried it and it seems you're right. So there are two solutions: 1) Supply images of size 320x480 / 640x960 with or without cleared status bar 2) Crop images (without status bar). 

To be conform to the HIG I'll choose option no. 1

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly fine to supply an image sized 320x460. The iPhone will display the status bar and your image underneath. I have an application in the AppStore with such an image and never ran into any problems with the review process.

If you supply an image sized 320x480, the status bar will overlay it.

Comment: Is it ok to use `default.jpg` and `default4.jpg` for the image names? Or does it have to be a png file?

Comment: You can use names other than Default.png, but you have to set it in your info.plist file for the key UILaunchImageFile. However, I think that you cannot use JPEG files.

Comment: Why cannot I use JPEG files? I think Xcode doesn't care about which image type I add. Or does all icons have to be in PNG format to conform the HIG?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the SDK just does not permit a .jpg-trailing value for UILaunchImageFile in your Info.plist (which you need to specify if you want to use another file than Default.png).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But an image of size 320x480 will not overlay the status bar. It is the other side round. The status bar overlay the image.

Answer (score 1):

I just used photoshop, selected the left most pixels in the status bbar (to get the gradient) and enlarged it to the right to cover all of the text / icons - this meant I had the status bar's gradient with no incorrect stuff on it.

It seemed to look OK.

Comment: Apple's Preview app is not bad either for stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

For the perfect screenshot you can run the following function on your phone if you wish:

```
    if (Camera.isSupported)
{
    if (CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData)
    {

        var cameraRoll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(deviceWidth,deviceHeight);
        bitmapData.draw(stage);
        cameraRoll.addBitmapData(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody states iOS for future reference

Comment: Do you see the words Cocoa touch in the question?